# how to separate every object populated in table from bd to a separate table paragraph using ASP.Net mvc5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

learning asp.net and came to a problem i can not solve yet, any help would be appreciated.
Here is the screen shot of how it is now:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHdpx.png)

and that how i want it to be on the web:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpgjt.png)

This is my table on Index page

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Главная страница";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<table>
       @foreach (var b in ViewBag.Events)
{
    <tr>
        <td style=" padding: 8px;"><p><h2>@b.Date</h2></p></td>
        <td style=" padding: 8px;"><p><h2>@b.Time</h2></p></td>
    </tr>
}
    <tr>      
        <td style="border: solid 1px grey; color: red; text-align: center; "><p><h3>Title</h3></p></>
        <td style="border: solid 1px grey; color: red; text-align: center; "><p><h3>Place</h3></p></td>
        <td style="border: solid 1px grey; color: red; text-align: center; "><p><h3>Lecturer</h3></p></td>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var b in ViewBag.Events)
{
    <tr style="padding: 80px;">
        <td style="border: solid 1px grey; padding: 8px; background-color: #ddc9ee;"><p><h4>@b.Title</h4></p></td>
        <td style="border: solid 1px grey; padding: 8px; background-color: #ddc9ee; "><p><h4>@b.Location</h4></p></td>
        <td style="border: solid 1px grey; padding: 8px; background-color: #ddc9ee; "><p><h4>@b.Responsible</h4></p></td>

    </tr>
}
</table>


<a href="CreateEvent" class="Button">Add Event</a>
```

Home controller

```
using PhClub.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace PhClub.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {   
        EventsContext db = new EventsContext();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {

            IEnumerable<Event> events = db.Events;
            ViewBag.Events = events;

            return View();

        }
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult CreateEvent()
        {
            return View();
        }
         [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult CreateEvent(AddEvent addEvent)
        {
            db.AddEvents.Add(addEvent);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return View();
        }
    }
    }
```

And second question - at the moment, when i add new event to Db with hardcoded ID it is not being populated with method above - any advise of where im going wrong?

Here is the table for event input i use,

```
<body>
    <div>
        <h3>Form of event creation</h3>
        <form method="post" action="">
            @*<input type="hidden" value="@ViewBag.AddEventId" name="AddEventId" />*@
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><p>Enter Id of event :</p></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="AddEventId" /> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><p>Enter title :</p></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="Title" /> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><p>Date:</p></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="Date" /> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><p>Time :</p></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="Time" /> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><p>Address :</p></td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="Location" />
                    </td>
                <tr>
                    <td><p>Lecturer:</p></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="Responsible" /> </td>
                </tr>                   
                <tr><td><input type="submit" value="Send" /> </td><td></td></tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current structure has two adjacent loops:

```
@foreach (var b in ViewBag.Events)
{
    [some output]
}
[more output]
@foreach (var b in ViewBag.Events)
{
    [even more output]
}
```

So you're looping over the events twice, effectively building two different sections of table divided by that output in the middle.  It looks like you want just *one* loop, where each iteration of the loop has a couple rows of table output.  Something structured more like this:

```
@foreach (var b in ViewBag.Events)
{
    [some output]
    [more output]
    [even more output]
}
```

This is untested of course, but perhaps in your code it would look like this:

```
@foreach (var b in ViewBag.Events)
{
    <tr>
        <td style=" padding: 8px;"><p><h2>@b.Date</h2></p></td>
        <td style=" padding: 8px;"><p><h2>@b.Time</h2></p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>      
        <td style="border: solid 1px grey; color: red; text-align: center; "><p><h3>Title</h3></p></>
        <td style="border: solid 1px grey; color: red; text-align: center; "><p><h3>Place</h3></p></td>
        <td style="border: solid 1px grey; color: red; text-align: center; "><p><h3>Lecturer</h3></p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="padding: 80px;">
        <td style="border: solid 1px grey; padding: 8px; background-color: #ddc9ee;"><p><h4>@b.Title</h4></p></td>
        <td style="border: solid 1px grey; padding: 8px; background-color: #ddc9ee; "><p><h4>@b.Location</h4></p></td>
        <td style="border: solid 1px grey; padding: 8px; background-color: #ddc9ee; "><p><h4>@b.Responsible</h4></p></td>
    </tr>
}
```

Basically, just loop over the records once and build the output you want for each record.

(For your second question, you may want to open a new Stack Overflow question.  To avoid confusion and keep things concise it's generally best to ask one question at a time.)

Comment: That did it! Thank you David